# Translating this sql statement to Zend_Db_Table

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have this test query that works fine:

```
select `name` from `Role` as rl, `UserRole` as ur 
WHERE rl.id = ur.roleId AND ur.userId = '1'
```

result: `'test'`

I 'm trying to use Zend_Table to do the same thing but I seem to be doing it wrong. Here 's what I 'm at:

```
$usrRole = new Schema_UserRole(array ('db' => $db));
$role = new Schema_Role(array ('db' => $db));
$select = $role->select();
$select
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array ('rl' => $role))
    ->join(array ('ur' => $usrRole), 'rl.id = ur.roleId')
    ->where('ur.userId = ?', '1');
$rowset = $role->fetchRow($select);
$out = $rowset->toArray();
```

Result: `''`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it seems it needs a string on the first parameter of `join`.

```
$select
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from($role, array('name'))
    ->joinLeft('UserRole', 'Role.id = UserRole.roleId', '')
    ->where('UserRole.userId = ?', '1');
```